# How to create an Eclipse Scala project in typesafe activator?

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

I have installed typesafe activator, created a project, added my own Scala classes and successfully compiled and run my code.

Now I was looking for a function to **eclipsify** my project using activator (similarly to what can be done with play) but I cannot find anything neither on the typesafe website nor by searching the internet.

Does activator provide such a function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cd` to the directory then type `activator eclipse`

For more options see here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE

Comment: @roterl: Ok. I had been using play v2.1 a while ago and didn't know about this. I thought there existed three tools: sbt, play (play framework), and activator (typesafe's tool). I did not know that typesafe was using the (new) play tool.

Comment: Play command was just a wrapper around the sbt. activator is a very similar, and provide all the functionality.

Comment: `activator eclipse

[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]        ^`

Comment: @tuler You need to follow the instructions here https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse and config your global sbt plugins folder. Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this from the Activator Web UI.
After selecting/opening your project, in the "Your application is ready" pop-up select "Code view & Open in IDE".
In the following code view there's the "Browse code" column.. to the right of the "Browse code" headline, there's a little gear wheel. That will open a menu that let's you open the project outside of Activator:

[image: Open project in Eclipse]

Comment: I'd already built for Eclipse but had Scala compiler errors return after a team member made some changes to our Play project and this option worked to resolve them. It did prompt me to recreate the files and after a Project>Clean in Eclipse everything compiled nicely.

Answer (score 2):

in SBT type eclipse, in activator select code/edit/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your project once so that it downloads the required sbt plugins.

Easy way to build is using the `activator ui`. Then in the "Code" tab click on "Build Eclipse project" or `activator eclipse` from the command line.